Converting a list of {"$oid": "string"} objects to a list of ObjectId in MongoDB
After a backend error that is now fixed, I have a corrupted database where the category_ids field is a list of objects with the key "$oid" instead of actual ObjectId objects.
I'm attempting to fix it with this query:

db.products.updateMany(
  {
    "category_ids": {
      $exists: true,
      $type: "array",
      $elemMatch: {
        "$oid": { $exists: true, $type: "string" }
      }
    }
  },
  [
    {
      $set: {
        "category_ids": {
          $map: {
            input: "$category_ids",
            as: "item",
            in: {
              $mergeObjects: [
                "$$item",
                {
                  "$oid": {
                    $cond: [
                      {
                        $and: [
                          { $ne: ["$$item.$oid", null] },
                          { $type: "$$item.$oid", $eq: "string" }
                        ]
                      },
                      { $toObjectId: "$$item.$oid" },
                      "$$item.$oid"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
);

But I get a "MongoServerError: unknown operator: $oid" error.
A sample document looks like this:
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "674e47d1aa9a78ec88c7bf07"
  },
  "name": "Apple iPhone 16 Pro 256GB Dorado",
  "listed": true,
  "price": 1902,
  "currency": "USD",
  "pictures": [
    "https://www.example.com/asset1",
    "https://www.example.com/asset2",
    "https://www.example.com/asset3"
  ],
  "group_ids": [],
  "category_ids": [
    {
      "$oid": "674df1c7aa9a78ec88c7be9b"
    },
    {
      "$oid": "674dff94aa9a78ec88c7be9f"
    }
  ],
  "custom_fields": {
    "description": "blah blah blah"
  }
  "variants": [],
  "variant_selection_mode": "image",
  "variant_selection_fields": []
}

Here's a screenshot comparing how a corrupted document looks like next to a non-corrupted one in MongoDB Compass:
screenshot
(top document is the corrupted one)
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you, peace

Please provide sample documents. Likely, you will find $getField useful.

As user Ray posted, an example would be helpful. MongoDB supports extended JSON (EJSON).  The use of $oid is seen often in EJSON.  It is still a valid document and holds an ObjectID, but usually represented in Base64.  For details on EJSON, see https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#mongodb-bsontype-ObjectId

Added sample document

This document appears to be EJSON.  It does not appear to be corrupted.

what tool are you using to query the data?

Im using MongoDB Compass, and I know it's corrupted because for non-corrupted documents I see ObjectId('...') not { "$oid": "..." } The corruption happened because when inserting them via python's pymongo library I inserted a dictionary with an $oid key instead of an ObjectId object from the bson library

Maybe show the screenshot of compass showing both variants?

Added screenshot requested by barrypicker
